# Config assistance with nginx & php5-fpm on ubuntu

Tags: nginx, php

I am trying to configure nginx with php-fpm (php v 5.3.5) on ubuntu 11.  Both nginx and php5-fpm are set to run as www-data.  nginx appears to serve html files but php files are not being served (log files generate a 404 error).  php5-fpm is running and listening on the same port that nginx is attempting to connect on (9000).  Config files are copied below.  Files are located in /var/www (www-data has read/write access to all files within that directory).

How can I go about troubleshooting this issue in order to figure out whether php5-fpm is even properly  receiving the request from nginx and whether it is unable to process the request because of incorrect privileges/incorrect config file location.

Any help would be appreciated.

**nginx.conf file:**

```
 user www-data;

    worker_processes 4;

    pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;

}

http 

{

    include mime.types;

    sendfile on;

    tcp_nopush on;

    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    # server_tokens off;

     server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    default_type application/octet-stream;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**default file in sites (enabled/available) folder:**

```
default

server 

{

    listen   80;

    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
        root   /var/www;

        index  index.html index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    }


    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {

      access_log        off;

      expires           30d;

      root /var/www;

    }



## Disable viewing .htaccess & .htpassword
    location ~ /\.ht {

        deny  all;

    }

include php.conf;

}
```

**php.config file in nginx directory:**

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;


location ~ \.php$

{

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;

    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED   $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING      $query_string;

    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD    $request_method;

    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE      $content_type;

    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH    $content_length;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME       $fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI       $request_uri;

    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI      $document_uri;

    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT     /var/www;

    fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL   $server_protocol;

    fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;

    fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE   nginx;

    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR       $remote_addr;

    fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT       $remote_port;

    fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR       $server_addr;

    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT       $server_port;

    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME       $server_name;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 600; # Set fairly high for debugging

    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;

    fastcgi_index index.php;

}
```

**log file output for php5-fpm**:

```
configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf test is successful
```

**log file output from nginx**:

```
"GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.220 Safari/535.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

aTo answer the original question. In you vhost configuration a part is missing, telling nginx what to do with the PHP files.

Example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME PATH_TO_YOUR_WEBSITE_ROOT$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

You could also look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-12-04 and if you plan to run multiple vhosts https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-nginx-with-php-pools-on-an-ubuntu-13-04-vps
Both tutorials show in a good way how to setup everything.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a bit in your server block that is meant to pass php files over `php5-fpm`.

e.g.

```
location ~ .php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

To write a new server block (the bit in `/site-enabled`), try using [this tool](http://tools.ajsalkeld.com).